# MS Login API asking for Admin consent for registering with MS azure App

Tags: java, authentication, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-identity

I have made one app for MS team integration for work accounts. In Azure AD I have consented to all permissions required for chats and channels. But still the app is asking for admin consent when people from other work account trying to login as below;

[image: [Admin consent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LijwI.png)]

Below screenshot is of API permissions;
[image: API permissions]

And I have below user setting for enterprise app as well;

[image: [User consent settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbprv.png)]

[Admin consent settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o24tS.png)

kindly help.

Comment: Could you check and confirm whether [this option](https://i.imgur.com/xJX04JX.png) is enabled in your tenant?

Comment: Hi Sridevi, Thanks for replying, Yes, It is enabled;

Comment: Could you include that screenshot by editing your question?

Comment: Hi Sridevi , question edited and added the screenshot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I registered one multi-tenant Azure AD application and granted same **`API permissions`** as below:

[image]

When I tried to sign in with user of another directory, I got below **`Approval required`** screen for justification like this:

[image]

After sending the justification, I got **same screen** as you saying `Request pending` like below:

[image]

To accept the above request, sign in with **Global administrator** account in above user's directory and check Admin consent requests tab  of Enterprise applications like below:

[image]

After clicking `Review permissions and consent` button, new window will be opened where Global Administrator can consent like below:

[image]

When I tried to sign in with user of another directory again now, new application registered with **same permissions** in that tenant like below:

[image]

In your case, you need to either **approve** Admin consent request or **disable** below option in other user's directory like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Sridevi,  Thank you for your reply, Admin consent issue resolved when admin approved the request via azure panel, under permission tab